# Why does Python think I'm doing modulo arithmetic when I try to print the result of a format expression?

Tags: python, eclipse, class, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class using PyDev in Eclipse, but when I try to run as Python I get an error:  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'`.

I've tried to select all text, then go under the source menu and select "correct indentation", but I could not find that option in my Eclipse.

How can I fix this problem in Python 3?

Here's the code (transcribed from [here](http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2013/07/24/130724042040537979.jpg)):

```
class Employee:
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print("Total Employee %d") % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name:"), self.name, "Salary: ", self.salary

def main():
    emp1 = Employee("Zara", 2000)
    emp2 = Employee("Manni", 5000)
    emp1.displayEmployee()
    emp2.displayEmployee()
    print("Total Employee %d") % Employee.empCount

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

No, indentation problems aren't your concern - the way you're printing out your information is.

In Python3, `print()` is now a function which returns `None` when done, then applying some operator to `None`, hence your exception.

I notice that you're attempting to do the old style of string formatting by using the `%` operator to specify when the formatting begins - the use of this in Python 3 is discouraged.

Here's how you get past it:  [use the curly-brace notation and call `.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) with the parameters you want to format.  It's positional, so multiple curly braces will format multiple arguments.

Example:

```
def displayEmployee(self):
    print ("Name: {}, Salary: {:d}".format(self.name, self.salary))
```

That's the most complex of your print statements; I feel that you can get the rest from here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have close the print function before entering all arguments, you should do the following:
 print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount) <-

By the way, in python 3, print have a new syntax and it requires parenthesis, so:

```
print ("Name:"), self.name, "Salary: ", self.salary
```

You have to write

```
print ("Name:", self.name, "Salary: ", self.salary)
```

I hope it works

Answer (score -1):

You have no indentation problems.

You are using three spaces to indent instead of four. This is not a problem for Python, but Eclipse thinks you should use four and puts wavy lines under it. If you can't get Eclipse to fix that, simply just use four spaces instead.